# Encountering error attempting to duplicate a disc on Mac using Disk Utility and "Burn Disc" tool: "The disc inserted does not have enough free space"

Tags: mac, optical-drive

I have a Mac/PC game with 4 discs. The first disc of the four was mishandled and became very scratched. I resolved to make a copy of it as a backup.

I first opened up Disk Utility and made a CDR file from the scratched disc, which finished successfully and I have confirmed the CDR file can be mounted.

I then took a blank CDR, selected the CDR file in Finder and went to File > Burn to Disc…

I cannot click the "Burn" button because I get the error message "The disc inserted does not have enough free space".

What's the problem? The CDR is just the image of another CD so it shouldn't be possible to be larger, right?

**Update**
The .cdr file is 765,757,440 bytes (765.8 MB) on disc according to the Finder inspector. Of course, CDs contain ~700MB of content, but as I said, this .cdr was created using Disk Utility from an existing, working disc.

Comment: Did you try another blank CDR?

Comment: Yes, and I can confirm the CDR has never been used

Comment: And the original disc isn't a DVD vs a CD?

Comment: It was a CD, no doubt about that

Comment: Back in the days games were issued on CD, manufacturers went to a lot of effort to make them uncopiable. Blank data segments, fake sizes, all kinds of methods. Unless you're absolutely certain the CD is not copy-protected, then that might be the root cause. I'd check with the game's developers to see if that is the case, or if they have a more modern downloadable version.

Comment: @Tetsujin, that's what I was thinking too. Well, it was worth a try, thanks!

Comment: The upside of a game that old will be that if it still runs, they probably sell it fresh to download for £$€ 5 or less these days - possibly less than the CDs you were going to burn it to ;) I'm currently playing GTA Vice City & GTA 4  inside a Windows VM, at speeds faster than I could have done on a real PC at the time - all for 6 bucks.